# Best way to delete an item from a JSON string using JsonUtility in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

What is the best way to delete an item from a JSON file using Unity 3d's JsonUtility?

I'm assuming you must load it, but: does it need to be parsed or converted to a list?

Once the operation is done, save it.
Any help for the middle part would be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm assuming you must load it, but: does it need to be parsed or
>   converted to a list?

Yes, with JsonUtility you must load it, convert it to  List then remove the item from it. First of all, the item must have a variable you can use to identify and remove it. Let's say that the name of the item to delete is "ken";

Test data to load serialize and de-serialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public string name;
    public int score;
}
```

Load(Must be loaded as array then converted back to List):

```
string jsonToLoad = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Data");
//Load as Array
PlayerData[] _tempLoadListData = JsonHelper.FromJson<PlayerData>(jsonToLoad);
//Convert to List
List<PlayerData> loadListData = _tempLoadListData.OfType<PlayerData>().ToList();
```

Remove all "ken" Items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loadListData.Count; i++)
{
    if (loadListData[i].name == "ken")
    {
        loadListData.Remove(loadListData[i]);
    }
}
```

or with Linq:

```
loadListData.RemoveAll((x) => x.name == "ken");
```

Then you can save it:

```
string jsonToSave = JsonHelper.ToJson(loadListData.ToArray());
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Data", jsonToSave);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Of-course, you will need `JsonHelper` as mentioned in your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660769/3785314) post.

Comment: THANKS Programmer!

Comment: No problem. Remember that you only need to load once, you can then continue to modify the loaded json data until you need to exit then save.

Comment: What if ken were a variable, would I still need the quotes?

Comment: What do you mean by "were a variable"?

Comment: string k="ken";                                                                                                                                     loadListData.RemoveAll((x) => x.name == k);

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: So if k="person: ken", then the line wouldn't work. You'd have to remove the chars before the string you really want with CharsToTrim, right?

Comment: I really don't understand your comment and your question. Can you rephrae with an example?

Comment: I apologize. I'm trying to pass in a variable rather than regular text, so that that item can be deleted from the list. So far it works hard coded, but not when I try to pass in a variable. I'll put the code above...

Comment: Please ask that as a new question because this is a different problem, I will take a look at it.